# javascript returning infinity ( quick power )

Tags: javascript

```
function pow(n,to){
  if(to == 0 ) return 1;  
  h = pow(n,to/2);
  return h*h* ((to % 2) == 0 ? 1 : n);  
}
```

Why does this code return infinity for power different than 0?

Comment: because you don't use `Math.pow()` !

Comment: What if `to` isn't a power of `2`? It will never be zero, no matter how many times you divide it by `2`.

Comment: @jAndy If I wanted to use Math.pow() I would. I use this for training purposes and question was why "this" code returns infinity, not how to calculate pow() in javascript.

Comment: Change `h=pow(n,to/2);` to `h=pow(n,Math.floor(to/2));` to ensure that `to` is always an integer.

Comment: @MattBall Ah ok. Your answer seems to be right. I assumed it's like in other languages that 1/2 = 0, but just checked and it's 0.5. How do I convert Number into Int? I know I probably can also floor it, but I don't want to.

Comment: There is no explicit int type in JavaScript. You need to round in some way: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion in your function will never stop. That is because `to / 2` will never be 0 when it's greater than 0. *to* will have these values throughout the recursion when you call it with an initial value of 10:

10 -> 5 -> 2.5 -> 1.25 -> 0.625...

You can use `Math.floor()` to cut off the part of a float after the decimal point. This is the function how you want it to be:

```
function pow(n, to) {
  if (to == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  var h = pow(n, Math.floor(to / 2));
  return h * h * ((to % 2) == 0 ? 1 : n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have infinite recursion. Meaning your function is calling itself and there is no condition to stop it from doing so. So it's calling itself forever until the javascript engine stops it. Put a console log in your function and watch it in the console.